# Why would Python think a file doesn't exist when I think it does?

Tags: python, exception, csv

I'm trying to import some files to plot, and all was going well until I moved my program to the directory above where it was before.  The relevant piece of code that seems to be problematic is below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd() + '/spectrum_scan/'
files = os.listdir(path)
dframefiles = pd.DataFrame(files)

up = pd.read_csv(dframefiles.ix[i][0])
```

If I type directly into the shell `os.path.exists(path)` it returns `True`.

The first file in the directory `spectrum_scan` is `foo.csv`.

When I type `os.path.exists(path + 'foo.csv')` it returns `True` but `os.path.isfile('foo.csv')` returns `False`.

Also, asking for `files` and `dframefiles` returns everything as it should, but when the code is run I get `Exception: File foo.csv does not exist`.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Fun debug trick. `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. This will invoke the debugger and halt execution. Then you can investigate the current state. As @Martijn Pieters points out below, you are missing the path. Dropping into the debugger would let you see that immediately and saves a bunch of print or log statements. I often wrap code with a try/except block catching everything that drops into pdb while I am developing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `os.listdir()`, which returns filenames *without* a path. You'll need to add the path to these:

```
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
```

otherwise python will try and look for `'foo.csv'` in the *current* directory, and not in the `spectrum_scan` sub-directory where the files really are located.

Comment: I only want the filenames in the pandas DataFrame though.  The code above worked when the program was in the directory `spectrum_scan`, all I've done is move it up a directory and add the `+ 'spectrum_scan'`

Comment: @user3087409: **exactly**;if you only pass in the filename without a path into the dataframe, it'll only work if those files are in the current working directory. You **have** to pass in filenames that can be loaded. Preferably you should use full, absolute paths.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I misunderstood.  Unfortunately the next part of the code does some sorting that only works for the plain filenames, I've got more work to do then.  At least I know what the problem is now though, thanks,